# How to change a background image to another background image in button while clicking using qml

Tags: qt, qt5.4

I need to change the background image of **button** from one image to other image while clicking using qml.

Here is my code :

```
Button{
    id:bu
    x: 121
    y: 40
    iconSource: "q.png"
    activeFocusOnPress: false
    opacity: 1
    checkable: true
    checked: true
    Layout.minimumWidth: 100
    Layout.minimumHeight: 100
}
```

The above code only sets the background image but, I need to change my background image on `onClicked` event or any other event using qml2.4.

Comment: Read the documentation before asking a question: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qmlfirststeps.html#handling-user-input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you will look at `Button` QML Type, you will find `clicked()` is the signal which is emitted when you will click the button. We can catch this signal in slot `onClicked` inside the qml and can change the `iconSource` property of the button

The code will be something like this:

```
    Button {
    id: bu
    x: 121
    y: 40
    iconSource: "q.png"
    activeFocusOnPress: false
    opacity: 1
    checkable: true
    checked: true
    Layout.minimumWidth: 100
    Layout.minimumHeight: 100

    onClicked: {
                bu.iconSource = "index.png"
            }

}
```

In this way you can change the screen background image of your button from one image to another.

**Update:**
For your requirement, you can use the below code:

```
property bool bImgChange: true

Button {
id: bu
x: 121
y: 40
iconSource: "q.png"
activeFocusOnPress: false
opacity: 1
checkable: true
checked: true
Layout.minimumWidth: 100
Layout.minimumHeight: 100

    onClicked: {
        if ( bImgChange == true )
        {
            bu.iconSource = "index.png"
            bImgChange = false
        }
        else
        {
            bu.iconSource = "q.png"
            bImgChange = true
        }
    }
}
```

You can use a user defined property  `bImgChange` and can use it for checking the condition.
Your condition will not work because `bu.iconSource` will give you the complete path where your image file exists. eg. `/home/user/some/path/q.png` and you are comparing this with the string `q.png` in your if condition.

I hope this will help.

Comment: thanks man, but i need changing image alternatively while clicking a buttononClicked: { if(  bu.iconSource = "q.png")
            bu.iconSource = "index.png"
        else   bu.iconSource = "p.png" } but it not working

Comment: Please try to mark this as an answer, once you get enough reputation. Thanks!